# Azure Comm Services Email Node.JS: How do I format connection string?

Tags: node.js, azure, email

I am trying to send an email using an azure comm service. I downloaded the Node.js demo and updated the index files to have my endpoint url and access key. However I may be formatting it wrong because I received an error stating that the endpoint is undefined. I changed the format then I get an error stating the access key is defined. I am very confused this is my first time doing this.

This is the portion of the code that keeps giving me errors, I have reformatted the connection string several times expecting it to be parsed and passed thus sending an email. However, this is not the case and I get errors stating either an endpoint or access key is undefined.

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// TODO: update when connection string format is finalized
const CONNECTION_STRING_REGEX =  endpoint = ("https://emailtesting.unitedstates.communication.azure.com/") ;accesskey =("xxxxxxxxx")
const tryParseConnectionString = (s) => {
const match = s.match(CONNECTION_STRING_REGEX);
if ((match === null || match === void 0 ? void 0 : match[1]) && match[2]) {
    return { endpoint: match[1], credential: new coreAuth.AzureKeyCredential(match[2]) };
}
return undefined;
};
/**
Returns an EndpointCredential to easily access properties of the connection string.
@hidden
@param connectionString - The connection string to parse
@returns Object to access the endpoint and the credentials
 */
const parseConnectionString = (connectionString) => {
console.log(ParseConnectionString)
const parsedConnectionString = tryParseConnectionString(connectionString);
if (parsedConnectionString) {
    return parsedConnectionString;
}
else {
    throw new Error(`Invalid connection string ${connectionString}`);
}
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes possible to send an email using an Azure comm service  in connection string

Comment: using this [MsDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/communication-email-readme?view=azure-node-latest)  [Output](https://i.imgur.com/6N0D3jY.png)

Answer (score 0):

***Send an email using an azure comm service.***

- Create a  Email Communication Services Domain.
- Create a Communication Service.
- Connect the Communication Service to Email Communication Services [Domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0in_d9Q2mU)

[image]

[image]

`npm install @azure/communication-email`

- In Communication Service in the Keys tab copy the Connection string.
- In Email Communication Service set the respective Provision domains -> MailFrom addresses and copy the mailid.

[image]

Code reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/communication-email-readme?view=azure-node-latest).

```
const  {  EmailClient  } = require("@azure/communication-email");
async  function  sendEmail()  {
const  connectionString = `endpoint=https: communication.azure.com/;accesskey=`;
// Initialize the EmailClient
const  emailClient = new  EmailClient(connectionString);
// Define the email message content
const  message = {
senderAddress:  "DoNotReply@ed.azurecomm.net",

content:  {

subject:  "This is the subject",

plainText:  "This is the body",

},
recipients:  {
to: [
{
address:  "customer@domain.com",
displayName:  "Customer Name",
},
],
},
};
try  {
const  poller = await  emailClient.beginSend(message);

// Poll for the email sending status and wait until it's done

const  response = await  poller.pollUntilDone();

console.log("Email sent successfully:",  response);

}  catch (error) {

console.error("Error sending email:",  error);
}
}
sendEmail();
```

**Output:**
[image]